# Error with loading 2 different versions of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using 2 JQuery versions on my website, but there is a problem with loading both versions at the same time. If one runs, then other one can't run. I am using Date Time picker and High charts. I have already searched for code to handle JQuery conflicts, but I don't understand them. I am new to JQuery.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

These are used for the date time picker.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

And these is used for the high charts. Please tell me a simple way that I can load both at the same time.

Comment: Why you are using two jqueries?

Comment: Importing two different versions of jQuery into the same page is a recipe for pain, heartache, and disaster.

Comment: You can create an alias for each of the versions, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: Have you considered using just the newer jQuery library, loaded first?

Comment: no firstly i was using date time picker and now i want to use high charts in the same page

Comment: But why do you use an old version of jQuery and jQuery UI for the datetimepicker? Why not use the same one Highcharts uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not tested but you could probably make use of the noConflict and setting them to diffrent shortnames

something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $jq1=jQuery.noConflict (); </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $jq2=jQuery.noConflict (); </script>
```

Then use the first one as $jq1('whaeverselector')...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't need to load the JQuery library twice.

```
//load JQuery Library
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
//load Jquery UI Library
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
//load the code for highcharts
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
//load the css for JQuery UI
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fairly unwise.

If you have a dependency that won't use a higher version of jquery then that dependency limits you to that particular jquery version.

My advice would be that you can only ever have one jquery instance loaded at a time. You could try noConflict(), but this is likely to cause trouble with any dependent libraries that may not implement this perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable due to jQuery's noconflict mode.

http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then, instead of

```
  $('#selector').function();
```

you'd do

```
 jQuery_1_3_2('#selector').function();
```

or

```
jQuery_1_1_3('#selector').function();.
```